# Black Ops 2 Zombies permanent perks

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I've seen many articles online claiming that there are permanent perks in Tranzit that can be unlocked through challenges. I've managed to earn permanent quick revive by reviving the  same player 15ish times. However, there are supposedly other permanent perks that you can earn such as phd flopper, stamina-up, and one that allows you to rebuild stronger barriers.

I've searched all over through Google looking for ways to get these perks. But, all I've managed to find are discussion boards talking about them with contradicting solutions for how these perks can be unlocked, or Youtube videos showing a player with the perk unlocked without any explanation of how to get it.

If anyone can provide a solid testable answer listing which permanent perks can be unlocked, and explanation of how to get them it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This link will help.
http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/how-to-get-permanent-perks-will-be-updated.817134/

It provides detailed information about the permanent perks and how to get them.
Although, note that "Deadshot Daiquiri" can only be earned after round 3.